# AngularJS with Entity Framework Core throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Trying to run AnglarJS on my website just executing simple $scope variable and cannot get it to work and throwing errors (image attached). Seems simple but I tried everything, correct me if I am missing any statement. Using VS Code, Entity Framework Core. Page renders perfect.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<head>
@section scripts{
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/SPA/pController.js"></script>
<script src="~/SPA/app.js"></script>
}
```

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="pController">

<p{{ word }} /p>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

app.controller('pController', pController);

**pController.js**

```
    var pController =  function($scope){
    $scope.data = null;
    $scope.word = "hello world";
};
pController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

RESULT:

[image: result]
[image]

**UDPATE**

Figured something, system cannot find the app.js file. Pasting all the code in html all works.

**SOLVED**

After a day spent on this problem, I solved it simply putting all my js Angular logic into /wwwroot/js/... I think somehow my project only read js files from that path. Thank you everyone for help!

Comment: what does entity framework have to do with your problem?

Comment: you need to load jquery before angularjs

Comment: In development mode, do not use the minified resources. It will help you in troubleshooting the errors.

Comment: Also, `<p{{ word }} /p>`?? I thinks it should be `<p>{{ word }}< /p>`

Comment: <p> tag I changed only here because of code formatting

Comment: @alexhuang in <script> sources? I replaced, same issue still

Comment: what does the error message say? When you click on the link that is provided in the console.

Comment: @alexhuang here is the Angular website error page https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/error/$injector/modulerr

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the files in your html as:

```
  <script src="~/SPA/app.js"></script>
  <script src="~/SPA/pController.js"></script>
```

Then do any of those:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

pController:

```
  app.controller('pController',  function($scope){
        $scope.data = null;
        $scope.word = "hello world";
    });
```

**Or**

In case you are using minification:

Modify your app.js file as:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('pController', ['$scope', pController]);
```

Then your controller file:

```
 var pController =  function($scope){
    $scope.data = null;
    $scope.word = "hello world";
};
```

If this still didn't work :), put the whole code in one single js file 'app' and then try and let me know the issue.

Comment: tried both ways, not working. Have no idea what is the issue :(

Comment: `app.controller('pController', ['$scope', pController)];` is incorrect. It should be `app.controller('pController', ['$scope', pController]);`

Comment: @lealceldeiro I fixed that before, same thing

Comment: @Coding Figured something, system cannot find the app.js file. Pasting all the code in html all works.